# Filter inner documents with array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have a look at my collections below,

```
db={
  "replies": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c4814d09488145b72beda9"
      },
      "post": [
        {
          "$oid": "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087"
        }
      ],
      "likes": [],
      "text": "Reply not reported",
      "comment": {
        "$oid": "60c4813f09488145b72beda8"
      },
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c4815609488145b72bedaa"
      },
      "post": [
        {
          "$oid": "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087"
        }
      ],
      "likes": [],
      "text": "Reply reported",
      "comment": {
        "$oid": "60c4813f09488145b72beda8"
      },
      "__v": 0,
      "reportCount": 1,
      "reportedUsers": [
        {
          "$oid": "6252fe50a5cbd65064d4aab8"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fca1877111f570dc3eb7088"
      },
      "replies": [],
      "text": "Reported comment",
      "post": {
        "$oid": "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087"
      },
      "reportCount": 1,
      "reportedUsers": [
        {
          "$oid": "6252fe50a5cbd65064d4aab8"
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c4813f09488145b72beda8"
      },
      "replies": [
        {
          "$oid": "60c4814d09488145b72beda9"
        },
        {
          "$oid": "60c4815609488145b72bedaa"
        }
      ],
      "text": "Comment not reported",
      "post": {
        "$oid": "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087"
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get comments and replies from post (Object id - 5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087). Assume I blocked user with id "6252fe50a5cbd65064d4aab8". In this case the results should not contain the first comment with id "5fca1877111f570dc3eb7088" reportedUsers contains the above mentioned id and the reply with id also need to filter out since it is also reported.
Both comments are comes under post "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087". Can somebody help with the aggregate query for filter comments and replies under post "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087" if the reported users includes user id "6252fe50a5cbd65064d4aab8".

[Mongodb playground url](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7P7Rk34EQQh)

Please let me know any more details needed.

Expected output will be list of comments with expanded list of replies like below,

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60c4813f09488145b72beda8",
    "replies": [
      {
        "_id": "60c4814d09488145b72beda9",
        "post": "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087",
        "likes": [],
        "text": "Reply not reported",
        "comment": "60c4813f09488145b72beda8"
      }
    ],
    "text": "Comment not reported",
    "post": "5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087"
  }
]
```

Comment: will be very helpful if you add in your question the expected document response

Comment: Hi @derek-menénedez, updated question with expected output, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

according to your comment that `$oid` represents `ObjectId`, and assuming a post can have several reported user, you can do something like this:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "post": ObjectId("5fc67eb5111f570dc3eb7087")}
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      reportedUsers: [
        {
          $match: {reportedUsers: { $ne: []} }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            reportedUsers: 1
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$reportedUsers" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: 0,
            rep: { $addToSet: "$reportedUsers"  }
          }
        }
      ],
      ok: [ {$match: {reportedUsers: null}} ]
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$ok"},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "replies",
      localField: "ok.replies",
      foreignField: "_id",
      let: {
        reportedUsers: "$reportedUsers"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            reportedUsers: {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$reportedUsers",
                []
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "ok.replies"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ok: 1,
      reportedUsers: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$reportedUsers",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "replies": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$ok.replies",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: {
                  "$setIntersection": [
                    "$$item.reportedUsers",
                    "$reportedUsers.rep"
                  ]
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      reportedUsers: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$ok._id",
      post: "$ok.post",
      replies: 1,
      text: "$ok.text"
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3yPL4y5wapS)

This query is `$match`ing all the comments for the required post, then split it to comments without `reportedUsers` (ok) and group all the `reportedUsers`, via a `$facet` step. Then it collects all replies from the replies collection, via `$lookup` and adding an empty `reportedUsers` array if it does not exists. Next step is filter the replies and remove all replies that has a reported user that was in our list of `reportedUsers` grouped before.

Comment: Hi @nimrod-serok, thanks for your answer $oid is ObjectId.
I wanted to filter comments with reported users includes id "6252fe50a5cbd65064d4aab8" and filter replies with reported users includes id "6252fe50a5cbd65064d4aab8".

Comment: As far as I can tell, my result is matching your expected output. Is there a difference?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts bro, 
Instead of {$or: [{reportCount: 0}, {reportCount: null}]} this i need to exclude results that contains the id in reportedUsers. The Id can be changed cannot be same as in the example.
{$eq: ["$$item.text", "Reply not reported" ]} - here also the text will not always "Reply not reported", here also we need to check the id exists inside reportedUsers inside replies

Comment: Edited according to last comment

Comment: Is it working for you?